# Can't flash anything from SD card

Tags: cyanogenmod

Not able to update the cm13 through the  recovery. whenever I try to update it gives the error message saying that can't mount the file or the file isn't found in the destination folder . Actually I have formated the SD card as internal storage and also I can access the SD card but can't flash anything in the recovery.

Comment: Formatting the SD card as internal storage probably caused this. I believe that when you format it in this way it formats it in a weird format but just a guess... Don't know how you would get around this issue without reformatting the SD or storing ZIPs on the Internal Storage. If anyone has a solution for this I would be happy to hear it!

Comment: Are you using TWRP? Have you updated to the last version? What phone are you using?